# WSO2APIM Message Mediation - API call blocked

Tags: wso2-api-manager, access-control, xacml, abac, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to test out XACML policies defined in WSO2 IS through WSO2 API Manager, as explained in the following link

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Enabling+Role-Based+Access+Control+Using+XACML

The policy is getting validated and I can see the "Permit" decision in the logs, but the API manager doesn't returns any response and the call is blocked and the request gets timed out after some time.

```
    DEBUG - EntitlementMediator Entitlement Decision is : Permit
    DEBUG - EntitlementMediator User is authorized to perform the action
    DEBUG - EntitlementMediator OnAccept sequence is not defined.
    INFO - SourceHandler Writer null when calling informWriterError
    WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-19 Socket Timeout : 60000 Remote Address : /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:63398
    WARN - TimeoutHandler Expiring message ID : urn:uuid:045f7259-cc8b-46a7-b9a2-832429163531; dropping message after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT of : 120 seconds for Endpoint
```

Pasting the message mediation policy file

```
            <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"  name="EM">     <entitlementService xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" remoteServiceUrl="https://localhost:9443/services" remoteServiceUserName="admin" remoteServicePassword="admin" callbackClass="org.wso2.sample.handlers.entitlement.APIEntitlementCallbackHandler">
                                            <onReject>
                                                            <makefault version="soap12">
                                                                            <code xmlns:soap12Env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                                                                                            value="soap12Env:Receiver"/>
                                                                            <reason value="UNAUTHORIZED"/>
                                                                            <node/>
                                                                            <role/>
                                                                            <detail>XACML Authorization Failed</detail>
                                                            </makefault>
                                                            <respond/>
                                            </onReject>
                                            <onAccept>
                                            <log level="trace" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
                                                            <send>
                                                                            <endpoint>
                                                                                            <address uri="http://localhost:8080"/>
                                                                            </endpoint>
                                                            </send>
                                            </onAccept>
                                            <obligations/>
                                            <advice/>
                            </entitlementService>
            </sequence>
```

If I just use respond in OnAccept, instead of send, the call returns immediately, but my back end API doesn't get called.

Am I missing something here ?

Thanks,  Albie Morken

Comment: Can you share your synapse file for that API?

Comment: Updated the message mediation policy file

Comment: decided to bypass WSO2 API Manager, since it didn't work as expected

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this

1. is not an issue with XACML but rather with the API manager
2. you did not define a happy path for when the PDP replies Permit. You can see that from     `DEBUG - EntitlementMediator OnAccept sequence is not defined.`

Try defining that path

Comment: It didn't worked ! I added the OnAccept sequence, still the call hangs ! <onAccept>
            <log level="full" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
                <send>
                    <endpoint>
                        <address uri="https://localhost:8080"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </send>
                <respond/>
            </onAccept>  I am just getting timeout error Expiring message ID : urn:uuid:448797c5-1c5e-41cf-aa59-1b8d31ee1067; dropping message after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT of : 120 seconds for AnonymousEndpoint, URI 
Not sure what's happening